# Button to the right inside a textbox (is this the best way to do it?)

Tags: html, css, input

Would my solution (inserting a button and floating it to the right of my textbox) be the best to do this, also would it be cross browser compatible at an HTML 5 standard?

It also seems that my [+] is a little off center from the top.

```
<style>
#refdocs_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    height: 20px;
    width: 179px;
}
#refdocs_button {
    clip:rect(1px 200px 19px 1px);
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
}
#refdocs_input {
    border: 0;
    width: 154px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 2px; 
}
</style>


<div id="refdocs_wrapper">

    <input id="refdocs_input" type="text">

    <input id="refdocs_button" type="button" value="+">

</div>
```

Comment: In Chrome the alignment is quite poor

Comment: I'd be careful with how Firefox renders the border, I've ran into a lot of situations with that.

Comment: The + is aligned far too low in my Firefox 22 Beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things.

Try this.

HTML:

```
<div id="refdocs_wrapper">
    <input id="refdocs_input" type="text"/><input id="refdocs_button" type="button" value="+"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#refdocs_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);

    line-height: 18px;
}
#refdocs_button {
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
#refdocs_input{
    width: 154px;
    padding: 0px; 

    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: clean and mean example...neat!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in css:

```
#refdocs_wrapper {
    position:relative;
 }
```

Then try to absolute the inner element with respect to outer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
#refdocs_wrapper{
...
position:relative;
}
#refdocs_button {
clip:rect(1px 200px 19px 1px);
position: absolute;
right: xx%; /* or left */
top: xx%; /* or bottom */
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
}
```

An element with absolute position is positioned relative to the closest relative position parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I got for Chrome, FF and IE.  FF is clearly the worst of them.  Note that I added ::-moz-focus-inner to help with the FF formatting.

http://jsfiddle.net/C7XEY/2/

Here is the CSS:

```
#refdocs_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    height: 20px;
    width: 179px;
}
#refdocs_button {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-indent: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#refdocs_input {
    border: 0;
    width: 154px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 2px; 
}
#refdocs_button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
```